# How to solve the following error of tensorflow gpu?

Tags: python, tensorflow

File "train.py", line 50, in 
    model.fit(x=[H_input, H, SNR], y=H, batch_size=256, epochs=50000, verbose=2, validation_split=0.1, callbacks=[reduce_lr, checkpoint])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 66, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 848, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 580, in **call**
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 644, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2420, in **call**
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1665, in _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1746, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 598, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  In[0] and In[1] must have compatible batch dimensions: [9,1,64] vs. [64,9,1]
     [[node model/lambda_1/MatMul (defined at /content/drive/My Drive/BF-design-with-DL-master/BF-design-with-DL-master/utils.py:28) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1697]

Function call stack:
train_function

Answer (score 0):

looks like you're creating a list in the wrong order somewhere `must have compatible batch dimensions: [9,1,64] vs. [64,9,1]`

Comment: is there any way to reshape the dimension? If possible please let me know